# Testing a component that depends on store from context

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, redux, jestjs

I'm having trouble setting up tests for a component that relies on a redux store passed down from context...

My app has a root component that gives its children the redux store as context:

```
import ApplicationStore from './app-store.js'

class Root extends Component {
    getChildContext() {
        return { store: ApplicationStore }
    }
    render(){...}
}

Root.childContextTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object,
};
```

I have a component that depends on the store (passed down from context):

```
class List extends Component {
  render(){
    const items = this.context.store.getState();

    return items.map((_, i) => (
      <div key={i}>{_.name}</div>
    ));
  }
}

List.contextTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object,
};
```

So my question is: How to I "inject" the store object into my component's context? Would I have to `unmock(./app-store.js)`?  Additionally, how can I pre-fill the store with a couple fixtures?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this does not answer your question, but I would like to point you to the React.js documentation on contexts:

> Most applications will never need to use context. Especially if you are just getting started with React, you likely do not want to use context. Using context will make your code harder to understand because it makes the data flow less clear. It is similar to using global variables to pass state through your application.

and

> Do not use context to pass your model data through components. Threading your data through the tree explicitly is much easier to understand. Using context makes your components more coupled and less reusable, because they behave differently depending on where they're rendered.

If you use props to pass your store (or even only the required parts of it) to your child components, then your problem is already solved because in your test, you can simply inject your mocked or stubbed store.

Comment: Thanks, @Nicole.  I read through that when I wrote the app and decided to pass store as context, but I didn't think it through all the way.

Comment: Also, if you are using React with Redux, you should use the official "React Redux" library to hook your components to the store ( https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux ).  It manages the store subscription for you.  From there, you can focus on just testing your "plain" component that just takes in props, and the `mapStateToProps` functions you write, and not have to worry about trying to test anything involving a store.  See the [Usage With React](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) and [Writing Tests](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html) docs pages.

Comment: Thanks, @markerikson.
I ended up wrapping my root component with `<Provider />` from react-redux.